# A question about connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be connected, open and have a bounded complement. Let $u\in C$ and $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuous injective function such that $f(0)=u$. It is also given that $f([0,1))\subseteq C,f(1)\notin C$. Does it follow that $C-f([0,1])$ is connected ?

I really think that the answer is yes and the proof would be short, however I can't figure it out.

Comment: Using stereographic projection, the question is closely related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287062/the-complement-of-jordan-arc

Comment: @Serios I have no idea about jordan curves If you can include a more elementary proof it would be great.

Comment: I feel there is an easy proof because the claim seems very intuitive

Comment: A jordan curve is one that does not cross itself.

Comment: Like with Jordan curves properties, it seems obvious when one tries to draw an example. But for a short elementary proof? Let's see what all the clever people out there will find.

Comment: @julien I will try again

Comment: By the way, where does the question come from?

Comment: @julien I was trying to prove that n+r=q+2 for planar graphs

Comment: where $n,q$ are the number of vertices and edges repex=ctively. r is the nmber of regions

Comment: Editing the title to bump the question after *two hours*? Come on.

Comment: @Chris Eagle I don't understand

Comment: Ah, so in view of Euler's formula, this amounts to showing that the number of faces is equal to the number of regions, right?

Comment: @Chris Eagle The reason why I edited it the title is because I did not get an answer. I wanted to inform MSE users that the question is still unsolved. I thought some people will not look at the question because it is solved. Now that there is a new answer I will remove the "still unsolved"from the title of the question

Comment: @Julien I got stuck into this question while trying to prove that all tres have 1 region

Comment: Ah I see. Does it mean that in your case, $f$ is actually affine?

Comment: I found myself asking a similar question and this [MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33049/a-jordan-arc-in-the-unit-disk/) answered mine.

Answer (score 1):

Since $C$ is open and connected, it is also path-connected.
Let $C' = C \setminus \operatorname{img}(f)$.
We prove that $C'$ too is path-connected.

Let $a, b ∈ C'$ and $γ \colon [0..1] → C$ be a path connecting those two points.
If $\operatorname{img}(γ) ⊂ C'$ then there is nothing to show.

So let's assume $\operatorname{img}(γ) \not⊂ C'$, meaning $\operatorname{img}(γ) ∩ \operatorname{img}(f) ≠ ∅$.
The intersection of those paths must be closed, so following $γ$ we eventually arrive at a *first* point of intersection (which isn't $a$) and at a *last* point of intersection (which isn't $b$).

Now since is $[0..1]$ is compact, $\operatorname{img}(f)$ is hausdorff, $f$-images of closed sets are indeed closed in the image of $f$ and since $f$ is injective, $\operatorname{img}(f)$ is indeed homeomorphic to $[0..1]$.

This implies that $\operatorname{img}(f)$ is locally connected, so we can cover it with a corresponding collection of open disks. We can find a Lebesgue number $r > 0$ such that any $r$-ball around a point in $\operatorname{img}(f)$ lies in the union of the covering.

Now their union yields some kind of inflation of the path $f$, so that it is open.

The idea is to jiggle $f$ around in this inflation such that it continues $γ$ to $a$ and $b$. But I fear I can't finish this argumentation, for one has to consider the boundary as well and I'm getting tired. So instead I made this beautiful picture in gimp using my trackpoint:

[image: beautiful]

Comment: I will read your answer shortly

Comment: It seems to me that this is essentially the same argument as ofer's. And like in ofer's argument, the end is not so obvious.

Comment: @julien Yes, and I was pretty angry with him that he posted it before me. : - (

Comment: These things happen all the time over here...

Comment: Don't forget the weird continuous functions

Comment: Complete the proof. Pick $x,y\in C$ not in $f([0,1])$. Let $t^*$ be the supremum of all $t$ such that there is a path connecting $x,y$ in $C$ and that is disjoint from $f([0,t])$. Show that $t^*$ must be a maximum. Then show that it must therefore be one.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ consists of a union of simply connected sets iff $U$ is open. Notice that deleting the arc is the same as adding an arc to a closed set which is a component of the complement. But the closed set plus the arc clearly deformation retracts onto the original closed set, so it is simply connected iff the original is. So we see that adding the arc does not change the connectedness of the set.

Answer (score 0):

We can show that for every $x \in U \setminus f([0,1])$, we can get from $x$ to $u$ with a curve in $U \setminus f([0,1])$.

Let $g$ be the curve that connect between $x$ and $u$ in $U$.
If $f$ and $g$ don't intersect, we're done.

Otherwise, let $y$ be the first point where the two curves intersect. $f$ is injective, therefore exists unique $0<t<1$ s.t. $ y=f(t)$.

The set $[0,t]$ is compact in $U$ open set, therefore there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $B(f([0,t]), \delta) \subset U$. It's easy to see that the set $B(f([0,t]), \delta) \setminus f((0,t))$ is connected. So there exists a curve $h$ from $f(t)=y$ to $f(0)=u$ and by concatenation of $h$ with the first part of $g$ which connect from $x$ to $y$, we'll get a curve in $U \setminus f([0,1])$ from $x$ to $u$.

Edit:
I've mistakenly shown that $U \setminus f((0,1))$ is connected. So to fix it, for $x,y \in U \setminus f([0,1])$, do the same process as describe above for $t_0,t_1$ where $f(t_0), f(t_1)$ are the first and last intersections of the original curve between $x$ and $y$ and the curve $f$.

Comment: But $u=f(0)$ is not in this set.

Comment: You are right. Fixed it.

Comment: Is it really that easy to see that the set $B(f([0,t]),\delta)\setminus f((0,t))$ is connected?

Comment: I agree with julien: If $T$ is a "tubular neighborhood" of the path $f$, then it is intuitively true that $T\setminus f\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ is connected, but a rigorous proof is welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

The complement $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash C$ is a homeomorphic image of finitely many disjoint closed balls. Now you can apply *Jordan arc theorem*, and you are done.