# Separation of Euclidean Space

Tags: general-topology, affine-geometry, connectedness, dimension-theory-analysis

Consider a finite collection $\mathcal{H}$ of hyperplanes of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that have a common line. Given some $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that is homeomorphic to a subset of $\bigcup\mathcal{H}$, what are some **necessary conditions** on $A$ such that $\mathbb{R}^n - A$ is disconnected?

I don't think the Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem can be used as $A$ cannot be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n - 1}$.

**My speculation**

I think $A$ must be unbounded; in fact, it must stretch to infinity in all directions, otherwise any two points can be linked by a path bypassing $A$.

I think $A$ must also be simply connected, or else any two points can be connected by a path piercing a hole in $A$.

A related (unsolved) question: [A question about connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305514/a-question-about-connected-sets-in-mathbbr2)