# How to extend an interval to a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

Let $$\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$ be a $C^0$ imbedding.  How can I show that there exists another imbedding $$\eta :  [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$ with $\eta ((0,1)) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 - \gamma [0,1] $ and $\gamma (0)= \eta (1), \gamma (1) = \eta (0)$? Thank you for yor help!

Comment: What kind of machinery are you allowed to use? There is a pretty easy way to do this but it may not be accessible to you.

Comment: May be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287062/the-complement-of-jordan-arc?lq=1

Comment: hmm. maybe give me a sketch and I'll see if it sounds like something I might understand?

Comment: @Cameron Williams :  Actually I think I'd almost prefer a short high tech proof.  I think those tend to be more enlightening