# Is every simple continuous curve on a plane a sub-curve of a simple continuous closed curve?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness, low-dimensional-topology, path-connected

Let $P:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a simple continuous curve on the plane, i.e. $P$ is continuous and injective. Can we always extend it so that it is a sub-curve of a simple closed curve?

It's equivalent to showing that $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash P((0,1))$ is path-connected.

I am only interested in the two dimensional case, but feel free to present a proof with $\mathbb{R}^n,n\geq 2$ replacing $\mathbb{R^2}$.

The fact that $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash P([0,1])$ is path-connected should be useful, see [The complement of a simple non closed curve is path connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955479/the-complement-of-a-simple-non-closed-curve-is-path-connected).

Answer (score 1):

After surfing over stackexchange I have found an answer.

Let $n\geq 2$. Given that every path-connected Hausdorff space is simple path-connected, see [Does path-connected imply simple path-connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522642/does-path-connected-imply-simple-path-connected), it suffices to show that $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash P((0,1))$ is path-connected.

Using results in [The complement of a simple non closed curve is path connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955479/the-complement-of-a-simple-non-closed-curve-is-path-connected), we have that $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash P([0,1])$ is path-connected.

Let $A:=\mathbb{R}^n \backslash P([0,1])$, it suffices to show $A\cup \{P(0),P(1)\}$ is also path-connected.

We need to use the following lemma from [When is the closure of a path connected set also path connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162867/when-is-the-closure-of-a-path-connected-set-also-path-connected).

**Lemma**: Let $S\subset X$ be path-connected and $x\in \overline{S}$. Suppose there exists a countable decreasing (i.e. $U^{i+1}\subset U^i$) neighborhood basis $(U_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ in $X$ at $x$ such that for each $i$, whenever $s_i\in S\cap U_i$ then there exists a path in $S\cap U_i$ from $s_i$ to some element of $S\cap U_{i+1}$. Then $S\cup \{x\}$ is path-connected.

Apply the above lemma twice to $A$ then we have the desired result.

Comment: You still have to show that Lemma applies in your setting. But, in fact, there is a stronger result: Every simple arc in the plane is ambient-homeomorphic to a line segment.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yeah I am just being lazy so I skipped the details of that part. Do you have a reference for the stronger result?

Comment: See answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57766/why-are-there-no-wild-arcs-in-the-plane).