# Extending a homeomorphism between two curves

Tags: general-topology, abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there “essentially only 1” Jordan arc in the plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17062/is-there-essentially-only-1-jordan-arc-in-the-plane)

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a simple curve with $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$ and $\gamma(1) =(1,0)$. Clearly, $\gamma$ is a homeomorphism onto $\gamma([0,1])$. Is it possible to extend $\gamma$ to a homeomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: It does not really matter what the endpoints are; we can always arrange them to be what we want with an affine map. The bottom line is: [there are no wild arcs in the plane](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57766/). Versions of this question came up before: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287062/the-complement-of-jordan-arc) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17062/is-there-essentially-only-1-jordan-arc-in-the-plane).