# Is there an injective $C^1$ curve dense in the plane?

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

Is there a curve $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ injective and $\mathcal{C}^1$ whose range is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Probably useful: the image of a smooth curve defined in a compact interval is [nowhere dense](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/70112/8157).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Now apply Baire Category.

Comment: @JSchlather: This shows the image of $\gamma$ must be meager, but that doesn't mean it can't be dense.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah, yes I'm mixing up parts. My mistake.

Comment: Here's a conjecture: if $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, then $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus E$ is connected.  Being connected and open, it is path connected.  If this holds,  it should be possible to use induction to construct an injective curve passing through every point in a countable dense subset.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like that should be the case. Is that really only conjectured? It seems like, even if you couldn't prove it, you could construct the curve inductively so that you knew it was true for $E_n$ the image of $[0,n]$. @NateEldredge

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: by "conjecture" I mean "seems like it should be true, but I couldn't think of a proof within 5 minutes".  Someone must know whether it's true or not.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The issue is how to ensure the curve is $C^1$?

Comment: @JSchlather: I don't think that's a serious problem.  In any open path-connected set, you can join any two points by a $C^\infty$ curve (take a continuous curve and mollify it).  Then you just have to join the endpoint of your existing curve with the next target point, and tweak it a little to match the derivatives.

Comment: Yeah, $C^1$ is relatively easy, it would seem to me.

Comment: Ah, misread "Here's a conjecture..." as "There's a conjecture..." @NateEldredge :)

Comment: @NateEldredge: In fact, without loss of generality you can take $E=[0,1] \times \{0\}$, so your conjecture is true: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287700/extending-a-homeomorphism-between-two-curves

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given a countable subset $E=\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N_0\}\subset \mathbb R^2$, there is an injective $C^\infty$ curve $\gamma\colon [0,\infty)\to\mathbb R^2$ passing through all points of $E$. To show this, we define $\gamma_n\colon [0,n]\to\mathbb R^2$ with

1. $\gamma_n\in C^\infty([0,n],\mathbb R^2)$
2. $\gamma_n$ is injective
3. $\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}\subset \gamma_n([0,n])$
4. There exist $ t_n\in[0,n)$, $r_n,s_n\in\mathbb R^2$ such that $\gamma_n(t)=t\cdot r_n+s_n$ for $t_n\le t\le n$

As a start, let $\gamma_1$ be the straight line segment from $x_0$ to $x_1$.

Now assume we are given  $\gamma_{n-1}$ that fulfills conditions 1.-4. (with $n$ replaced by $n-1$).
Let $S$ be the set of points $x$ such that there exists a curve $\gamma_n$ with $\gamma_n(n)=x$ and $\gamma_n|_{[0,n-1]}=\gamma_{n-1}$ and fulfiling conditions 1., 2. and 4. (but not necessarily 3.).

Then $S$ 
contains $B(\gamma_{n-1}(n-1),\delta)\setminus\gamma_{n-1}([t_{n-1},n-1])$ where $\delta$ is the (positive) distance between $\gamma_{n-1}(n-1)$ and the compact set $\gamma_{n-1}([0,t_{n-1}])$. This is so  because we can add a tiny linear segment to the desired endpoint and make a smooth connection between two line segments. 
By a similar construction, $S$ is open.
Again by asimilar construction, $\mathbb R^2\setminus(S\cup\gamma_{n-1}([0,n-1]))$ is open. Since $\mathbb R^2\setminus\gamma_{n-1}([0,n-1])$ is connected, we conclude $S=\mathbb R^2\setminus\gamma_{n-1}([0,n-1])$. Especially, we can either select $x=x_{n}$ and thus obtain $\gamma_n$ with conditions 1.-4. fulfilled and $\gamma_n|_{[0,n-1]}=\gamma_{n-1}$.
Or we already have $x_n\in\gamma_{n-1}([0,n-1])$ "by accident" and can choose $x$ arbitrary and reach the same goal.

The curve $\gamma\colon [0,\infty)\to\mathbb R^2$ with $\gamma(t)=\gamma_n(t)$ for some $n>t$ then fulfills

1. $\gamma\in C^\infty([0,\infty),\mathbb R^2)$
2. $\gamma$ is injective
3. $E\subset\gamma([0,\infty))$

If $E$ is a dense set, we conclude that $\gamma([0,\infty))$ is dense.